# Images not show in ReactJS carousal slider

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a Carousel slider on my website but all of the images are not showing. I'm using an example provided by a library but it's not working.

I've linked the Bootstrap CDN in my HTML file but it does not help.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Carousel,} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Carousel from 'nuka-carousel';
class Slider extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Carousel autoplay={true}>
                <img src="../asset/img1.jpg" />
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide2" />
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide3" />
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide4" />
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide5" />
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide6" />
            </Carousel>
        );
    }
}
export default Slider;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: no just show blank page

Comment: When you look at the console, are there any error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You are using 2 different Carousels from 2 different library's I'm sure this will cause some issues.

Remove `import Carousel from 'nuka-carousel';`

I would stick to using `react-bootstrap` version

**install package**: `npm install --save react-bootstrap`

**Add stylesheet** to your HTML:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Make sure you are importing it properly like so:

`import {Carousel} from 'react-bootstrap';`

The [example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/) from the actual `react-bootstrap`

```
class ControlledCarousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      direction: null
    };
  }

  handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
    alert(`selected=${selectedIndex}, direction=${e.direction}`);
    this.setState({
      index: selectedIndex,
      direction: e.direction
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { index, direction } = this.state;

    return (
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={index}
        direction={direction}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
      >
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/carousel.png" />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>First slide label</h3>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/carousel.png" />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Second slide label</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/carousel.png" />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Third slide label</h3>
            <p>
              Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
            </p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
    );
  }
}

render(<ControlledCarousel />);
```

Comment: thank you for you answer but im using his library,its not work fine just show balnk page @Paul Mcloughlin

Comment: Okay, well get rid of `import {Carousel,} from 'react-bootstrap';`

Comment: is this related to load bootstrap cnd to my browser? @Paul Mcloughlin

Comment: Well, you're including it, and it's not being used. So why are you including it?

Comment: i think its not load complete @Paul Mcloughlin

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: because im using many library but all of this library using bootstrap not working and one of them not using bootstrap work fine @Paul Mcloughlin

Comment: have you any idea  about add another cnd bootstrap @Paul Mcloughlin

Comment: Without seeing your component I can't advise.

Comment: I'm using your example code now but it's not work @paul Mcloughlin